# \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} vs amsfonts, amssymb

Tags: unicode-math, tex-gyre-math, amsfonts

I used to always include `amsfonts`, `amssymb` in my preamble.
I have now started using XeTeX, with

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

I understand that `\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}` causes TeX to use the glyphs from the TeX Gyre Pagella Math font, which is downloaded on my machine.

As far as I can tell, this is making the inclusion of `amsfonts`, `amssymb` redundant. Are there still reasons to include `amsfonts`, `amssymb`?

Comment: there may (possibly) be reasons for example if you are particularly wedded to the ams `\mathbb` design and don't like the tex gyre ones but you have to undo a lot of what unicode-math does to enable 8-bit fonts to work in conjunction with unicode-math so never simply routinely load the packages.